# Are all solids mono-atomic? Is there not any di-atomic metals or compounds?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, chemical-compounds

I want to know whether all solids are mono-atomic or not, and if there was diatomic solids or not,and if there was compounds of solids.

Comment: Ice is not monoatomic, for a simple example. You may find intro chemistry courses helpful in learning more.

Comment: I guess iodine is diatomic and solid at room temperature.

Comment: Table salt? Most organic solids?

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I am treating this question as on-topic to the extent that the molecular make up of material is a matter of concern to physics is cases like crystal structure and so on. That said, the question seem to be based on a fairly complete lack of understanding about the basics of what is being asked. Could be considered for closure under the homework rule on that account.

Answer (score 5):

Talking about (solid) metals as monoatomic or diatomic is somewhat tricky (solids are not like gasses), with discrete structures freely bouncing around.  They are clumped together in large lattices, with each neighbour interacting with each other neighbour.  In essence, something like a lump of gold is a N-atomic lattice of atoms.